# data.table objects aren't updated in Rstudio environment panel

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

A data.table object in the environment panel will not update its preview after new variables are added using the `:=` method. However `str(dt)` shows the correct details, and assigning `dt` to a new variable results in the correct preview in the Environment panel.

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10,
                 y = log(1:10),
                 z = (1:10)**2)
dt[, a := x + y, ]
dt[, b := x + z, ]
str(dt)
d <- dt
```

Is this by design, a known bug or is there a solution to this? The behavior is interesting, and I am curious as to the reason this is happening.

Comment: You can still refresh the list of objects in the environment manually, though.

Comment: Fyi, you want `data.table(x = 1:10, y = ...)` instead of `as.data.table(cbind(...))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like RStudio only updates environment panel when objects are created, or when you hit refresh button (as pointed by @lukeA).
I don't think the *bug* is good word here, it can be a design concept of RStudio to update structure of objects only in particular scenario, and not investigate what each user's call is, to decide if refresh is required.
But I understand it is not desired behavior for RStudio users, but I think it better fits as *feature request* to detect by reference calls than a *bug report*.

This behavior is consistent comparing to `dir.create()` which creates directory as a side effect. It is also not updated in working directory panel always.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped clear up my confusion. It is an interesting concept. Every other object in the environment panel (that I've used) updates/refreshes when changed.

Comment: @Mitch I believe it depends if you update making an in-memory copy, or update by reference. The latter one is used for efficiency, so not really useful for metadata, but definitely useful for data.