# RStudio environment pane incorrectly displays some modified data tables

Tags: r, rstudio

My RStudio environment pane does not update certain `data.table` s.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
#Create data table dt1
dt1 <- data.table(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6)
```

The environment pane, as expected, displays this:

[image: dt1]

Now I add a column to dt1

```
#Add a third column using ':=' notation
dt1[, col3 := 7:9]
```

but the environment pane still shows this:

[image: dt1 not updated]

Next, consider an identical `data.table` dt2:

```
#Create data table dt2
dt2 <- data.table(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6)
```

The environment pane shows:

[image]

Now I add a third column to dt2 using '$' notation

```
#Add a third column using '$' notation
dt2$col3 <- 7:9
```

and the environment pane correctly updates:

[image]

Interestingly, when both lines of code for dt1 are run at the same time

```
#Create data table dt1
dt1 <- data.table(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6)
#Add a third column using ':=' notation
dt1[, col3 := 7:9]
```

the pane correctly updates:

[image]

**How can I cause the environment pane to correctly update when adding a column with a separate command using the ':=' notation?**

I'm running R 3.2.4, RStudio 0.99.893 and `data.table` 1.9.6 in Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure why you care about this, but you should report it to the Studio support.

Comment: You are almost certainly aware of this, but just in case: you can force the environment pane to update by clicking the little arrow.

Comment: @Roland I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: @Stibu Thanks, but I don't recall having to use that function at any other time.  Perhaps I shouldn't assume that the pane automatically provides correct information.

Comment: @Robert Actually, I also never (consciously) encountered the situation you describe and have never used that button before. Pressing the button is just a workaround that you can use until the bug (?) is corrected. (For this to happen you should probably follow Roland's advice...)

Comment: The issue here is that `data.table` objects get updated by reference, and RStudio doesn't detect these changes (ie, it only detects copies of objects).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data.table objects aren't updated in Rstudio environment panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921206/data-table-objects-arent-updated-in-rstudio-environment-panel)